# Don’t start in insert mode when opening a shell script

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode, startup, filetype-sh

How can I prevent vi from starting in insert mode when opening a "test.sh"-like file with the vi-plugin "bash-support" v4.3 ?

- When I `vim test.sh` it opens in insert mode
- When I `vim .vimrc` it opens in normal mode

I would like to disable this behavior

plug-in
https://github.com/WolfgangMehner/bash-support

Comment: Maybe open an issue in the plugins [bug-trracker](https://github.com/WolfgangMehner/vim-plugins/issues).

Comment: does that plugin set up any interesting autocommands (e.g. FileType)?